# hmvc load controller Cannot redeclare class CI

Tags: codeigniter-3, hmvc

i developed an CMS in codeigniter 2 with HMVC and now im trying to migrate to Codeigniter 3. I have the follow issue.

This works in view codeigniter 2

```
<?PHP $configuracion = $this->load->controller('configuracion/todos');
?>
```

I recive the error: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class CI in /home/xxxx/public_html/application/third_party/MX/Base.php on line 57

This is the controller:

```
<?php

class Configuracion extends MX_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('configuracion_m', 'Configuracion_m');
```

}

```
function todos() {
    return $this->Configuracion_m->get_all();
}
```

Thanx!!!!!